# Classifiying a set of Images into Classes

Tags: python, image, classification, descriptor, pca

I have the problem that I get a set of pictures and need to classify those.

The thing is, i do not really have any knowledge of these images. So i plan on using as many descriptors as I can find and then do a PCA on those to identify only the descriptors that are of use to me.

I can do supervised learning on a lot of datapoints, if that helps. However there is a chance that pictures are connected to each other. Meaning there could be a development from Image X to Image X+1, although I kinda hope this gets sorted out with the information in each Image.

My question are:

1. How do i do this best when using Python? (I want to make a proof of concept first where speed is a non-issue). What libraries should i use?
2. Are there examples already for an image Classification of such a kind? Example of using a bunch of descriptors and cooking them down via PCA? This part is kinda scary for me, to be honest. Although I think python should already do something like this for me.

Edit:
I have found a neat kit that i am currently trying out for this: http://scikit-image.org/ There seem to be some descriptors in there. Is there a way to do automatic feature extraction and rank the features according to their descriptive power towards the target classification? PCA should be able to rank automatically.

Edit 2:
I have my framework for the storage of the data now a bit more refined. I will be using the Fat system as a database. I will have one folder for each instance of a combination of classes. So if an image belongs to class 1 and 2, there will be a folder img12 that contains those images. This way i can better control the amount of data i have for each class.

Edit 3:
I found an example of a libary (sklearn) for python that does some sort of what i want to do. it is about recognizing hand-written digits. I am trying to convert my dataset into something that i can use with this.

here is the example i found using sklearn:

```
import pylab as pl

# Import datasets, classifiers and performance metrics
from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics

# The digits dataset
digits = datasets.load_digits()

# The data that we are interested in is made of 8x8 images of digits,
# let's have a look at the first 3 images, stored in the `images`
# attribute of the dataset. If we were working from image files, we
# could load them using pylab.imread. For these images know which
# digit they represent: it is given in the 'target' of the dataset.
for index, (image, label) in enumerate(zip(digits.images, digits.target)[:4]):
    pl.subplot(2, 4, index + 1)
    pl.axis('off')
    pl.imshow(image, cmap=pl.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
    pl.title('Training: %i' % label)

# To apply an classifier on this data, we need to flatten the image, to
# turn the data in a (samples, feature) matrix:
n_samples = len(digits.images)
data = digits.images.reshape((n_samples, -1))

# Create a classifier: a support vector classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)

# We learn the digits on the first half of the digits
classifier.fit(data[:n_samples / 2], digits.target[:n_samples / 2])

# Now predict the value of the digit on the second half:
expected = digits.target[n_samples / 2:]
predicted = classifier.predict(data[n_samples / 2:])

print("Classification report for classifier %s:\n%s\n"
      % (classifier, metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted)))
print("Confusion matrix:\n%s" % metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))

for index, (image, prediction) in enumerate(
        zip(digits.images[n_samples / 2:], predicted)[:4]):
    pl.subplot(2, 4, index + 5)
    pl.axis('off')
    pl.imshow(image, cmap=pl.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
    pl.title('Prediction: %i' % prediction)

pl.show()
```

Comment: And what did you try so far? Show some effort mate.

Comment: i will edit the stuff in that i accomplish so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert a picture to a vector of pixels, and perform PCA on that vector. This might be easier than trying to manually find descriptors. You can use numPy and sciPy in python.
For example:

```
import scipy.io
from numpy import *
#every row in the *.mat file is 256*256 numbers representing gray scale values
#for each pixel in an image. i.e. if XTrain.mat has 1000 lines than each line
#will be made up of 256*256 numbers and there would be 1000 images in the file.
#The following loads the image into a sciPy matrix where each row is a vector
#of length 256*256, representing an image. This code will need to be switched
#out if you have a different method of storing images.
Xtrain = scipy.io.loadmat('Xtrain.mat')["Xtrain"]
Ytrain = scipy.io.loadmat('Ytrain.mat')["Ytrain"]
Xtest = scipy.io.loadmat('Xtest.mat')["Xtest"]
Ytest = scipy.io.loadmat('Ytest.mat')["Ytest"]
learn(Xtest,Xtrain,Ytest,Ytrain,5) #this lowers the dimension from 256*256 to 5

def learn(testX,trainX,testY,trainY,n):
    pcmat = PCA(trainX,n)
    lowdimtrain=mat(trainX)*pcmat #lower the dimension of trainX
    lowdimtest=mat(testX)*pcmat #lower the dimension of testX
    #run some learning algorithm here using the low dimension matrices for example
    trainset = []    

    knnres = KNN(lowdimtrain, trainY, lowdimtest ,k)
    numloss=0
    for i in range(len(knnres)):
        if knnres[i]!=testY[i]:
            numloss+=1
    return numloss

def PCA(Xparam, n):
    X = mat(Xparam)
    Xtranspose = X.transpose()
    A=Xtranspose*X
    return eigs(A,n)

def eigs(M,k):
    [vals,vecs]=LA.eig(M)
    return LM2ML(vecs[:k])

def LM2ML(lm):
    U=[[]]
    temp = []
    for i in lm: 
       for j in range(size(i)):
           temp.append(i[0,j])
       U.append(temp)
       temp = []
    U=U[1:]
    return U
```

In order to classify your image you can used k-nearest neighbors. i.e. you find the k nearest images and label your image with by majority vote over the k nearest images. For example:

```
def KNN(trainset, Ytrainvec, testset, k):
    eucdist = scidist.cdist(testset,trainset,'sqeuclidean')
    res=[]
    for dists in eucdist:
        distup = zip(dists, Ytrainvec)
        minVals = []
    sumLabel=0;
    for it in range(k):
        minIndex = index_min(dists)
        (minVal,minLabel) = distup[minIndex]
        del distup[minIndex]
        dists=numpy.delete(dists,minIndex,0)
        if minLabel == 1:
            sumLabel+=1
        else:
            sumLabel-=1
        if(sumLabel>0):
            res.append(1)
        else:
            res.append(0)
    return res
```

Comment: can you add an example how to do this?

Comment: I added an example, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm not answering your question directly. But images vary greatly:remote sensing, objects, scenes, fMRI, biomedial, faces, etc... It would help if you narrow your categorization a bit and let us know.

What descriptors are you computing? Most of the code I use (as well as the computer vision community) is in MATLAB, not in python, but I'm sure there are similar codes available (pycv module & http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). Try out this descriptor benchmark that has precompiled state-out-the-art code from the people at MIT: http://people.csail.mit.edu/jxiao/SUN/ Try looking at GIST,HOG and SIFT, those are pretty standard depending on what you wanto to analyze: scenes, objects or points respectively.

Comment: is there a way to use all of those descriptors simultaneously? A PCA should then be able to weed out those who do not contribute. Can you make an example in python code?

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you are trying to solve it on a purely "programmer approach", instead of relying on computer vision literature that can give you a short cut. 

I believe you can mix some descriptors and hive a huge feature vector and normalize each vector, but your approach looks very "brute". You haven't even defined what type of images you are planning to use of the categories I mentioned before.

Comment: that is on purpose. i am trying to get by without resorting to computer vision stuff. i want the algorithm to figure out on its own what is important in the images. This should depend entirely on the data.

Answer (score 0):

First,import libraries and extract pictures

```
from sklearn import datasets    
%matplotlib inline
import sklearn as sk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
digits = datasets.load_digits()
X_digits = digits.data
y_digits = digits.target
ind4 = np.where(y_digits==4)
ind5=  np.where(y_digits==5)
plt.imshow(X_digits[1778].reshape((8,8)),cmap=plt.cm.gray_r)
```

Answer (score 0):

then use this feature:

xx = np.arange(64)

def feature_11(xx):

```
yy=xx.reshape(8,8)
feature_1 = sum(yy[0:2,:])
feature11 = sum(feature_1)
print (feature11)
return feature11
```

feature_11(X_digits[1778])

then use lda:

from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

clf = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()

ind_all = np.arange(0,len(y_digits))

np.random.shuffle(ind_all)

ind_training = ind_all[0:int(0.8 * len(ind_all))   ]

ind_test = ind_all[int(0.8 * len(ind_all)):]

clf.fit(X_digits[ind_training], y_digits[ind_training])

y_predicted = clf.predict(X_digits[ind_test])

plt.subplot(211)

plt.stem(y_predicted)

plt.subplot(212)

plt.stem(y_digits[ind_test], 'r')

plt.stem(y_digits[ind_test] - y_predicted, 'r')

sum (y_predicted == y_digits[ind_test]) / len(y_predicted)

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer. Only showing code can be confusing.